# how can get number from string object?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mobile

how can I get "9" from this string and put the value in long object

```
"["pusher-decision-voting-started",9]"
```

I tried convert the string to Json object but it is not worked with me

Comment: Hi! Use a library such as https://github.com/google/gson. If you bump into problems with that, feel free to ask a specific question about that on this site :)

Comment: You tagged both Kotlin and Java. Which do you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Single digit**:

```
val expression = "\"[\"pusher-decision-voting-started\",9]\""

val result : Long? = expression.firstOrNull { it.isDigit() }
       ?.toString()
       ?.toLong()
```

Bad habit: Will produce bad result if you want to seacth for more then 1 digit numbers.

**Multiple digits**:

```
val expression2 = "\"[\"pusher-decision-voting-started\",92]\""

val result2 : Long? = expression2.filter { it.isDigit() }
       .takeIf { it.isNotEmpty() }
       ?.toLong()
```

Bad habit: Will produce wrong result, if the numbers are not close together

Both results work with missing numbers. I hope it fits your case.

Answer (score 0):

hmm i don't know all the context and the whole requirements, but I would try this

```
long extractedValue = Long.valueOf(StringUtils.substringsBetween("[", "]").split(",")[1]);
or the java 8 Streams method
Long.valueOf(input.codePoints().filter(Character::isDigit).mapToObj(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("")));
```

but i recommend to do some cheks before

Comment: it will be more readable with the effective check, for example what about if the string is like this "["pusher-decision-voting-started"]", it will throw an exception on split

Comment: it's just a beggining example